# Evaluate mismatch in lidR

Tags: r, lidr

I'm working for a LiDAR integrator and I'm in charge of evaluating the strip adjustment algorithm we've developed.
I'd like to know if it is possible to evaluate the mismatch in `lidR`. And if yes how would you process?

To be more precise, I'd like to compute the average elevation differences between each strip and a meansurface (for instance ground surface).

Comment: I'm not asking if there is a strip adjustment algorithm in lidR but how you would process to evaluate it. For instance if there is a mismatch algorithm in lidR. Or if it could be possible to evaluate the mismatch between two or more flightlines by calculating the difference in Z on a flat surface. In fact I'm trying to think of graphs showing before/after the strip adjustment. And by that showing the interest of strip adjustment. If you have any idea it would be nice.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please edit your question to include a single, focused question. This will help help you get the best answer/s. Otherwise, open-ended questions are suitable on GIS SE chat once you have the sufficient reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is what your are looking for because your question is very broad but here a suggestion using a DTM. But you can use any other type of raster such as mean height, max height and so on.

```r
library(lidR)

LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Topography.laz", package="lidR")

# Original data
las1 = readLAS(LASfile)

# Create a mis-aligned version
las2 = las1
las2$X = las2$X + 1

# Create a realigned version
las3 = las2
las3$X = las3$X - 0.9

dtm1 = grid_terrain(las1, 1, tin())
dtm2 = grid_terrain(las2, 1, tin())
dtm3 = grid_terrain(las3, 1, tin())

err1 = dtm1 - dtm2
err2 = dtm1 - dtm3

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(err1, col = gray.colors(25,0,1))
plot(err2, col = gray.colors(25,0,1))
```

[image]

```r
hist(err1[], breaks = seq(-5, 5, 0.1))
hist(err2[], breaks = seq(-5, 5, 0.1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer which is for me a good start. I'll need to compute the ground for each strip separetly (is it possible in lidR to compute ground classification on each  strip  individually ?) . Then compute the mean surface. And then calculate the elevation difference between surfaces from individual strip and the mean surface.

Comment: If the strips are labelled you can split the strips and compute something on each.